# How can I do jQuery doesn't work for a specific element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this jQuery to FadeOut the page smoothly when you click on a "href" link.

I have an ecommerce, so I have a cart where you can see the products you have added. (Online Store: [www.backlabel.com](http://www.backlabel.com))

You can delete it from the cart directly with a "X" on the top of the product. This "X" have the "href" property, so the page load the jQuery and its bad because the whole page re-load.

I wish jQuery does not work just on the "X" button. Can i do it with an extra code in this follow jQuery?

```
// delegate all clicks on "a" tag (links)
$(document).on("click", "a", function (event) {
    // get the href attribute
    var newUrl = $(this).attr("href");

    // veryfy if the new url exists or is a hash
    if (!newUrl || newUrl[0] === "#") {
        // set that hash
        location.hash = newUrl;
        return;
    }

    // now, fadeout the html (whole page)
    $("html").fadeOut(function () {
        // when the animation is complete, set the new location
        location = newUrl;
    });

    // prevent the default browser behavior.
    return false;
});
```

Comment: for preventing the default browser behavior use event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can exclude an `href` from such a selection using `a:not('#yourID')` like that

```js
$(document).on("click", "a:not('#x')", function (event) {
  alert('clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" >Link1</a>
<a href="#" >Link2</a>
<a href="#" id="x">Link3</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("html").fadeOut(function () {
        // when the animation is complete, set the new location
        window.location = newUrl;
    });
```